# Heroku push fails with remote rejected

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

I get this error message:

> Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app. [remote rejected]
>   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push
>   some refs

package.json

```
{
    "name": "devconnector",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Social network for developers",
    "engines": {
        "node": "8.11.4"
    },
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
        "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
        "start": "node server.js",
        "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
        "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
        "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
    },
    "author": "Cara Adelson",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
        "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "gravatar": "^1.6.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
        "mongoose": "^5.3.12",
        "passport": "^0.4.0",
        "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
        "validator": "^10.9.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "nodemon": "^1.18.6"
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your `node_modules` folder to `.gitignore`. [This page](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) may help you.